# How do I make kendo grid row fully hyperlinked?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I have made my kendo grid row selectable but after googling I can't find anything that shows me how to make the row a hyperlink.  I want someone to be able to click anywhere on the row and go to the url provided.  I tried row template and that broke my grid.  This is done in asp.net MVC.

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<EmployeeMasterView>()
              .Name("grid")
              .Columns(columns =>
              {
                  columns.Bound(e => e.EmployeePicture).ClientTemplate("<img src='" + Url.Content("~/Content/img/#: EmployeePicture#") + "' height='50px' width='50px' />").Title("Picture").Width(100);
                  columns.Bound(e => e.FirstName).Width(120).ClientTemplate("<a href='" + Url.Action("Index", "Employees", new {E="#: EmployeeID#" }) + "' >#: FirstName#</a>");
                  columns.Bound(e => e.LastName).Width(120);
                  columns.Bound(e => e.EmployeeID).Width(120);
                  columns.Bound(e => e.Email).Width(200);
                  columns.Bound(e => e.Department).Width(155);
                  columns.Bound(e => e.StrGender).Title("Gender").Hidden(true);
                  columns.Bound(e => e.BlnInactive).Title("Inactive").Hidden(true).ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' #= BlnInactive ? checked='checked' : '' # disabled='disabled'></input>");
              })
              .Sortable()
              .Selectable()
              .Scrollable()
              .Groupable()
              .ColumnMenu()
                //.Pageable()
              .Filterable()
              .ClientDetailTemplateId("template")
              .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:600px;" })
              .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
              .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
              .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                  .Ajax()
                  //  .PageSize(10)
                          .Read(read => read.Action("DetailTemplate_Employees", "Employees"))

              )
              .Events(events => events.DataBound("dataBound"))
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

You could handle the change event

```
.Events(events => events.Change("onChange").DataBound("onDataBound"))
```

And then in the change event javascript, get the selected row's dataItem, find the URL and launch it.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-change

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right path with using the row template.  You should be able to customize the example from http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/rowtemplate to serve your purpose.

If you are having trouble, post your code so we can have a look at it.